# How many people read exactly one newspaper (A B C)?

Tags: probability

Event A = Read A. 
Event B = Read B. 
Event C = Read C.

$P(A) = 0.20, P(B) = 0.26 , P(C)=0.14$ 
$P(A \cap B) = 0.08$ 
$P(A \cap C) = 0.05$ 
$P(B \cap C) = 0.04$ 
$P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.02$

How many people read Exactly one newspaper ?

So, it would be $P[(A \cap \lnot B \cap \lnot C) \cup (\lnot A \cap B \cap \lnot C) \cup (\lnot A \cap \lnot B \cap C)]$ ? 
 
I have the answer here and it says 0.28 but I can't get the right answer. Anyone can help ?

Comment: It cannot be determined, unless we make highly implausible assumptions, such as independence.

Comment: I tried with independence, I think. For example $P(A \cap \not B \cap \not C)$ I calculated like this: 0.20 * 0.76 * 0.86 which I guess it is wrong !?

Comment: That is right. And there are two other terms calculated in the same way. Then we can add.  So we can certainly obtain an answer if we assume independence.

Comment: NB: Use `\lnot A` ($~\lnot A~$) rather than `\not A` ($~\not A~$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must also give the values of $P(A \cap B), \ P(B \cap C), \ P(A \cap C), \ P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

$ \ P(A \cap B \cap C)=2$

$ only\ A \cap B = \ P(A \cap B)\cap\lnot (A \cap \ B \cap C)=8-2=6 $

$ only\ B \cap C = \ P(B \cap C)\cap \lnot (A \cap \ B \cap C)=4-2=2$

$ only\ A \cap B = \ P(A \cap C)\cap \lnot (A \cap \ B \cap C)=5-2=3$

$only A=20-3-2-6=9$

$only B=26-2-2-6=16 $

$only C=14-3-2-2=7$

The answer is
 $(7+16+9)/100=0.32$

Comment: The question gives the values. I fixed it.